# Unix : Run a script on a different machine at a particular time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, solaris

I am working on a script which gets the script name and time to run that script and login /host name from a configuration file.

I **dont** have cron,at and crontab permission.

Now is there any other way to implement the logic to run a script on the input time (set in a configuratble file) from another script running on different host.

**In Detail:**
It is like script_A reads a configuration file from where it gets three inputs script_B , time to run (ddmmyyyy h24:mm:ss),login1@machine1. This script_B has to be run at a time provided on the given host.

**None of the connected machines have cron,crontab,at permissions**

I am using solaris

Can we have something like this in unix that the script_A creates a script_c which have the script_B with a check on time parameter. Now this script_c is copied to remote machine and it keeps running there in background till the time provided is reached.Once the time has come it execute script_b (located at remote host in the config file) and exit.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have the permission for crontab, then probably the sysadmin and/or the owner of the machine disallow doing that, and you should not go against that: in some countries (e.g. in France) illegal access or abuse of a computer is a criminal offense. So you should speak to people, not try to circumvent the rules they defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute command foo at epoch time xxxxxxxxxx on host, you could do:

```
$ delay=$((xxxxxxxxxx - $( date +%s ))); test $delay -gt 0 &&
        sleep $delay && ssh host foo
```

Comment: what will happen to my initial script (script_A) , will it wait there till the time this script_B is not executed or this command will create a pid on the host and run when instantiated.

Comment: As written above, this will pause until the time expires.  You can simply spawn a background process that does the pause.  This is a very simplistic solution and will not scale well.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to compile `cron` from source and deploy it on the target machine. Every time your code gets any kind of control over the machine, check if your `cron` daemon is running (classic PID file) and start it if necessary.

#### A warning, though:

This is a *social problem* and a technical solution. Your mileage will be low.

Comment: To deploy `crond` the poster probably needs root access to the target machine. (And Thiton's warning is so important that I made it a bold title)